# C `sendto` versus `write`

Tags: c, raw-sockets

Correct me if I'm wrong, but my understanding of sending a raw packet inevitably is defined as buffering an array of bytes in an array, and writing it to a socket. However, most example code I've seen so far tend towards `sendto`, rarely is `send` used, and I've never seen code other than my own use `write`. Am I missing something? What is with this apparent preoccupation with complicating code like this?

Why use `send` and `sendto` when `write` seems to me to be the obvious choice when dealing with raw sockets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`sendto` is typically used with unconnected UDP sockets or raw sockets.  It takes a parameter specifying the destination address/port of the packet.  `send` and `write` don't have this parameter, so there's no way to tell the data where to go.

`send` is used with TCP sockets and connected UDP sockets.  Since a connection has been established, a destination does not need to be specified, and in fact this function doesn't have a parameter for one.

While the `write` function can be used in places where `send` can be used, it lacks the `flags` parameter which can enable certain behaviors on TCP sockets.  It also doesn't return the same set of error codes as `send`, so if things go wrong you might not get a meaningful error code.  In theory you could also use `write` on a raw socket if the `IP_HDRINCL` socket option is set, but again it's not preferable since it doesn't support the same error codes as `send`.

Comment: According to Posix (and a similar statement in linux and freebsd manpages), "If the socket argument refers to a socket and the flags argument is 0, the send() function is equivalent to write()." I think the only send-specific error are `ENOTSOCK` and `EOPNOTSUPP`, neither of which are relevant to `write`.